# Upgrading PHP from 7.1 to 7.2 with Homebrew in macOS but still seeing PHP 7.1

Tags: macos, php, homebrew

I am trying to upgrade my PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2 on macOS and with Homebrew.

I did the following steps:

```
brew install php72

brew services stop php71
brew unlink php71

brew link php72
brew services start php72
```

Everything seemed to work fine. When I do `php --version` I get:

> PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2018 21:40:59) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

But if I try to run a PHP script with `phpinfo()` the information still says PHP Version 7.1.20.

If I run `brew services list` I have the following services running:

```
dnsmasq    started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
mariadb    started xy       /Users/xy/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
nginx      started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php        started root     /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
php@7.1    stopped
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

`brew unlink php71` and `brew link php72` will tweak your php command line to the right path and version, but Apache will not be affected until you change its config file.

First, locate your `httpd.conf` file path:

```
httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

You may also check:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Then:

- Open your `httpd.conf` file and locate the line starting with `LoadModule php`
- Comment this line with `#`, and add your 7.2 line instead.
  You can get your line from querying the following command in the Terminal:
- `brew info php@7.2 | grep LoadModule`
- it should look like: `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`
- Finally, restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`
- your script should now be runing with php7.2 version

---

There's also detailed instructions about [using a php switcher here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions). Once installed, you can switch from one version to another like this (it will link both Apache and the command line automatically):

```
sphp 7.1
sphp 7.2
sphp 5.6
etc..
```

Comment: This  is a good answer. But Apache needs to be restarted for the new module to be picked up.